# Automatic creation of derived classes from an associated settings class?

Tags: c#, xml, instance, derived-class

I'm trying to automatically instantiate the correct derived class based on the derived settings class.

Here I have the main base class along with a base settings class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() { }

    public abstract BaseClassSettings Write();
}

public class BaseClassSettings
{

}
```

Now here are my derive classes and their settings classes

```
public class DerivedFoo : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedFoo(DerivedFooSettings settings) 
    { 
         // Apply settings
    }

    public override BaseClassSettings Write()
    {
        DerivedFooSettings settings = new DerivedFooSettings();

        return settings;
    }
}

public class DerivedFooSettings : BaseClassSettings
{

}

public class DerivedBar : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedBar(DerivedBarSettings settings) 
    { 
         // Apply settings
    }

    public override BaseClassSettings Write()
    {
        DerivedBarSettings settings = new DerivedBarSettings();

        return settings;
    }
}

public class DerivedBarSettings : BaseClassSettings
{

}
```

I can save all the derived class settings in one array

```
DerivedFoo foo = new DerivedFoo();
DerivedBar bar = new DerivedBar();

BaseClassSettings[] s = new BaseClassSettings[2];
s[0] = foo.Write();
s[1] = bar.Write();
```

which serializes to disc in XML format.

How can I automatically instantiate the derived classes based on the derived settings classes?

So if the array element is a DerivedBarSettings class create a new instance of the DerivedBar class.

I would like to do this without using an ever increasing number of else if statements depending on the number of classes.

```
if (BaseClassSettings is DerivedFooSettings)
    new DerivedFoo(settings)
else if (BaseClassSettings is DerivedBarSettings) 
    new DerivedBar(settings)
```

How can this be done?

===============================================================================

[EDIT]

Here's what I am using:

```
[
    XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedSettingsClassA)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedSettingsClassB)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedSettingsClassC)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedSettingsClassD)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedSettingsClassE)),
]
public abstract class BaseSettingsClass
{
    public abstract DerivedClass Load(Game1 game, OutputDimensionSettings settings);
}
```

The only downside to this is that I have to explicitely define XmlInclude for all derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?

Here's one way (there are other possibilities):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{ 
  public abstract BaseClassSettings Write(); 
} 

public abstract class BaseClassSettings
{
  public abstract BaseClass CreateCorrespondingInstance();
}
```

Then:

```
public class DerivedFoo : BaseClass             
{             
  public DerivedFoo(DerivedFooSettings settings)              
  {              
    // Apply settings             
  }             

  public override BaseClassSettings Write()             
  {             
    DerivedFooSettings settings = new DerivedFooSettings();             
    return settings;             
  }             
}             

public class DerivedFooSettings : BaseClassSettings             
{             
  public override BaseClass CreateCorrespondingInstance()
  {
    return new DerivedFoo(this);
  }
}
```

But it looks like you could benefit from generics!

Comment: I can assure you that this isn't homework (unless you count ongoing work towards an objective as homework, so maybe it is).  I'm writing a prototype for my PhD project that isn't computer science based.  I would like to learn how to utilize the benefits of generics in this case, can you (or others) help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure generics are going to be of much help here. Generics are used to defer or constrain a type this is unknown until compile time. What you are doing is creating a relationship between unrelated types. This can be done with a custom attribute and some reflection.

First our custom attribute:

```
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class BaseClassLinkAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public System.Type LinkedType { get; set; }

        public BaseClassLinkAttribute(Type linkedType)
        {
            // Probably wat to make sure type is derrived from BaseClass
            LinkedType = linkedType;
        }
    }
```

Now we add a static method to our base class that creats an instance of the type in the custom attribute:

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{ 
    public BaseClass() 
    { 
    } 

    public abstract BaseClassSettings Write();

    public static BaseClass CreateFromSettings(BaseClassSettings settings)
    {
        Attribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(settings.GetType(), typeof(BaseClassLinkAttribute));

        // Check for null here and throw exception if attribute can't be found in prduction code

        BaseClassLinkAttribute linkAttribute = (BaseClassLinkAttribute)attr;

        // This is only going to work if class implements a constructor
        // that take a base settings class

        return (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(linkAttribute.LinkedType,settings);
    }
}
```

Now all we have to do is mark the settings class with the attribute of the class we want it to create.

```
[BaseClassLink(typeof(DerivedFoo))]
public class DerivedFooSettings : BaseClassSettings
{
}
```

So given a settings class, we can now create the assocated class:

```
       DerivedFooSettings x = new DerivedFooSettings();

       BaseClass y = BaseClass.CreateFromSettings(x);

       Console.WriteLine(y.GetType().FullName);
```

Which will give you the output of Namespace.DerivedFoo.

Of course there are some limitations here, the derrived class must implement a constructor that takes settings class or activiation will fail. I think we some work you might be able to get rid of the attrbiute and pass the type in with a generic. However, you will still have to create a link between the types.

Comment: I like your idea and I couldn't see the need to use generics.  I've rolled my own generation based on a combination of Jeppe's answer but I will study yours to see if it brings anything new.